# WebStorm: LESS not being compiled on Mac

Tags: css, less, webstorm

I have installed WebStorm 9 on Mac. I am having problems getting my LESS code compiled to CSS even after installing the LESS Compiler plugin.

The following message gets displayed:

> "Missing CSS Output Directory - You can add CSS output directories under Settings >  Project Settings > LESS Compiler"

Though there is no "Project Settings", I have add out put directory to LESS Compiler in "Settings".

It still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Known issue - see https://github.com/acdvorak/intellij-lessc-plugin/issues/47.
I can suggest using less compiler (`npm install -g less`) configured as a file watcher instread - see https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html

Comment: I have gone through this and tried it. But its still not working

Comment: what problems making file watcher work have you faced?

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the problem in mac WebStorm, finally found where is wrong:

WebStorm Less compiler only work for ver. less 1.6.2

please use below under your project:

```
sudo npm install less@1.6.2
```

then in **File Watchers** in WebStorm to edit Less watcher,
in **Program** field change path to:

```
yourProjectPath/node_modules/less/bin/lessc
```

then happy css will appear. :)